# add event and reminder is not working in LG Nexus 5 Marshmallow throwing this Exception except Nexus this code is working in all devices

Tags: android

add event and reminder is not working in LG Nexus 5 Marshmallow throwing this Exception  except Nexus this code is working in all devices

I m calling this method

```
addEvent(this, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+600000, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+900000, titleTimeArr[0]);
```

Exception comes in setReminder method in 
when control comes on this line

```
Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Code

```
public void addEvent(Context context,long startcalDate,long endcalDate,String title) {
    try {
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startcalDate);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endcalDate);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE,title);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID());
        System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID());
        Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

        // Save the eventId into the Task object for possible future delete.
        Long eventId = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        // Add a 5 minute, 1 hour and 1 day reminders (3 reminders)
        setReminder(cr, eventId, 5);
        setReminder(cr, eventId, 60);
       // setReminder(cr, eventId, 1440);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void setReminder(ContentResolver cr, long eventID, int timeBefore) {
    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, timeBefore);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, eventID);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
        Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, values); // Exception comes in this line
        Cursor c = CalendarContract.Reminders.query(cr, eventID,
                new String[]{CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES});
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            System.out.println("calendar"
                    + c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES)));
        }
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Exception

```
08-18 15:12:57.429 8740-8740/com.sntialtech.hondagbs W/System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException
08-18 15:12:57.435 8740-8740/com.sntialtech.hondagbs W/System.err:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:179)
08-18 15:12:57.435 8740-8740/com.sntialtech.hondagbs W/System.err:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
08-18 15:12:57.436 8740-8740/com.sntialtech.hondagbs W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
08-18 15:12:57.436 8740-8740/com.sntialtech.hondagbs W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1231)
08-18 15:12:57.436 8740-8740/com.sntialtech.hondagbs W/System.err:     at com.sntialtech.hondagbs.activities.InclusionScheduleActivity.setReminder(InclusionScheduleActivity.java:307)
08-18 15:12:57.436 8740-8740/com.sntialtech.hondagbs W/System.err:     at com.sntialtech.hondagbs.activities.InclusionScheduleActivity.addEvent(InclusionScheduleActivity.java:292)
08-18 15:12:57.436 8740-8740/com.sntialtech.hondagbs W/System.err:     at com.sntialtech.hondagbs.activities.InclusionScheduleActivity.parseTimeAndAddEvent(InclusionScheduleActivity.java:211)
08-18 15:12:57.436 8740-8740/com.sntialtech.hondagbs W/System.err:     at com.sntialtech.hondagbs.activities.InclusionScheduleActivity.onPressPermissionOk(InclusionScheduleActivity.java:140)
08-18 15:12:57.436 8740-8740/com.sntialtech.hondagbs W/System.err:     at com.sntialtech.hondagbs.utils.Utils.showPermissionDialog(Utils.java:98)
08-18 15:12:57.436 8740-8740/com.sntialtech.hondagbs W/System.err:     at com.sntialtech.hondagbs.activities.InclusionScheduleActivity.onItemClick(InclusionScheduleActivity.java:178)
08-18 15:12:57.436 8740-8740/com.sntialtech.hondagbs W/System.err:     at com.sntialtech.hondagbs.adapters.InclusionScheduleAdapter$1.onClick(InclusionScheduleAdapter.java:88)
08-18 15:12:57.436 8740-8740/com.sntialtech.hondagbs W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
08-18 15:12:57.436 8740-8740/com.sntialtech.hondagbs W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
08-18 15:12:57.436 8740-8740/com.sntialtech.hondagbs W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-18 15:12:57.436 8740-8740/com.sntialtech.hondagbs W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-18 15:12:57.436 8740-8740/com.sntialtech.hondagbs W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
08-18 15:12:57.436 8740-8740/com.sntialtech.hondagbs W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
08-18 15:12:57.436 8740-8740/com.sntialtech.hondagbs W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-18 15:12:57.436 8740-8740/com.sntialtech.hondagbs W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
08-18 15:12:57.436 8740-8740/com.sntialtech.hondagbs W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: have found any solution for this?

Comment: got any solution?

Comment: i didn't get ......

Answer (score 1):

This answer helped me with the same problem: [Cant set a calendar event on android 4.0 >](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802890/cant-set-a-calendar-event-on-android-4-0)

Replace Events.DTSTART, Events.DTEND with CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME repectively.